# How to authorize other users for google api with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

Here are my codes:

```
            var clientId = 'Client Id';
            var apiKey = 'Api Key';
            var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
 function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
    }

    function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);

    }


            function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
                if (authResult && !authResult.error)                    
                  makeApiCall();                                            // call the api if authorization passed
                else {                                                  
                    handleAuthClick;                
                }
            }
            function handleAuthClick() {
                gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
                return false;
            }
```

My question is when I login using my google account that created the project with client id, the authorization works well. But if I login using another google account, the functions above cannot authorize the application request for authorizing calendar api. Can anyone tell me how to authorize other users so that my app can manage their google calendar account? The app is a web application that can synchronize the calendar system of my web app with the google calendar.

Comment: You need to set the access token inside the `handleAuthResult` function: `accessToken = authResult.access_token;`

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is solved due to your help.